# LinearLayout does not return onFling?

Tags: android, android-layout

I expect to display one picture each time and horizontally swipe to another picture through onFling(). The problem is I have to use ScrollView to wrap my ImageView so as to get response from onFling. If I use Linearlayout to wrap the ImageView, nothing happens when I swipe. I don't want to use scrollview because the picture can be scrolled vertically though it is the exact screen size. How can I achieve it? Below is my layout.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_tutorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding an attribute `android:longClickable="true"` to the LinearLayout.